# Connect to Firebase Storage via Spring Backend

Tags: spring, firebase, maven, spring-boot, firebase-storage

I am struggling with hopefully a simple problem with regards to connecting to the firebase-storage database via Spring Backend Framework.

I have already managed to successfully connect to my firebase-database however when attempting to connect to firebase-storage using Maven, the firebase-storage dependency is not recognized.

**Below is the code I have attempted to use via Maven with no luck:**

```
<dependency><groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
<artifactId>firebase-storage</artifactId>
<version>11.4.2</version></dependency>
```

I would need to ultimately get the image download URL through the Spring Controller.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to access Cloud Storage from a backend system?  If so, the firebase-storage dependency is not for you.  That's for Android apps.

Comment: Yes, absolutely right, I got confused. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65462832/5869384

Answer (score 0):

So, I got a little confused and I was trying to use the Android Dependency instead of the Admin Server SDK.

In order to resolve the issue, I had to:

**Set the storage bucket (see below:)**

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/")
            .setStorageBucket("myapp.appspot.com")
            .build();
```

**Create a reference to it:**

```
 Bucket bucket = StorageClient.getInstance().bucket();
```